# How to implement flutter google place package

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-places-api

How to use flutter google place package and how to implement it only onscreen without opening a new screen in a flutter.

Flutter google place package - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0):

package support `Mode.overlay` 
when you call `PlacesAutocomplete.show` set `mode` to `Mode.overlay`

code snippet

```
body: Center(
      child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildDropdownMenu(),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _handlePressButton,
        child: Text("Search places"),
      ),
...
Widget _buildDropdownMenu() => DropdownButton(  
        value: _mode,
        items: <DropdownMenuItem<Mode>>[
          DropdownMenuItem<Mode>(
            child: Text("Overlay"),
            value: Mode.overlay,
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<Mode>(
            child: Text("Fullscreen"),
            value: Mode.fullscreen,
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (m) {
          setState(() {
            _mode = m;
          });
        },
      );
...   
Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
    // show input autocomplete with selected mode
    // then get the Prediction selected
    Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
      onError: onError,
      mode: _mode,
      language: "fr",
      components: [Component(Component.country, "fr")],
    );

    displayPrediction(p, homeScaffoldKey.currentState);
  }
```

You can copy paste run example directly 
full example 
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: I know but I want to search location on the custom text field.